# How do I remove "ghost" backups from Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, osx-el-capitan

If I check the Time Machine backup mount, I see this:

```
SilentMac:SilentMac almo$ ls
2015-02-28-102519   2015-05-17-121037   2015-11-08-161652
2015-03-29-194158   2015-06-25-022353   Latest
2015-05-04-211217   2015-09-05-185222
```

But if I go into Time Machine itself, I see a backup on Jan 4. But it says "Waiting...", and never displays any files. How do I clean this up so Time Machine only shows backups that actually exist?

I found this, too:

```
SilentMac:SilentMac almo$ tmutil listbackups
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-03-29-194158
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-05-04-211217
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-05-17-121037
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-06-25-022353
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-09-05-185222
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/SilentMac/2015-11-08-161652
```

But you can see that when I enter TimeMachine, it thinks there are more:

[image]

Comment: Argh... just got a tumbleweed badge for this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple must have fixed something... after a recent OSX update, these "ghost" backups just disappeared.